# for loop is run more times then specified.

Tags: python, for-loop, methods, pygame

I have been trying to make a drop down menu in pygame. I have a method that that takes a list of strings and renders them to the screen using a for loop. The for loop is shown below.

```
        spacer = 0
        for text in range(5):
            spacer += 30
            rect = pygame.Rect(0, spacer, 100, 20)
            pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, (255, 0, 0), rect)
            self.rect_list.append(rect)
```

I appended each rectangle that was created in the for loop to a list `rect_list`.
i then printed the list to the screen to see it's contents. The Python IDLE window was spammed with the contents of the list.

The method that contained in the for loop is being called in a second method of another class `Menu`. The method in class `Menu` is called in a while loop:

```
while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                running = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        #--------method being called in while loop----------#
        Menu_Class_Obj.render_menu()
        #--------method being called in while loop----------#
        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce, no output at all.

Comment: In the future I suggest revising your question to reduce the amount of information and code to the smallest amount possible. Create the shortest possible program that exhibits the undesired behavior. See also: sscce.org

Comment: @Rawing, Sorry forgot to add the print statement. Will do though

Comment: @Rawing What you have to do is in the top left corner click the `File` button. The hover your mouse over one of the red rectangles

Comment: @Mr.Python Looks like you're printing the list every time the mouse moves...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time your menu is rendered, you're appending to `menu_items_rect_list`. Whatever you put in that list will stay there indefinitely. If you want the list to be empty at the start of the frame, you need to clear it yourself.

Comment: I get what your saying, but I don't think It will get me my desired results. I want just the five rectangle that I added in my for loop to stay there so i can iterate over the list, not have an empty list.

Comment: Your issue is not with the for loop. You issue is with the code being called every frame since its in your render loop. On the first frame you will add ABCDE to the list. On the second frame you add them again, so you get ABCDEABCDE. You need to change your code so either the for loop is only called once at startup or your list is cleared before you start adding to it so you don't get duplicates.

Comment: ok I'll think I will try your suggestions and see if they work. Oh, and thanks for the link to sscce.org. Next time I ask a question I'll try to structure it better.

Comment: thanks for the advice. Even though I wasn't able to get any of your suggestions to work, they got me thinking and I eventual found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is very obvious once I really thought  about what was happing. Since I'm calling the method that contains the for-loop in a while loop, the for-loop is being run multiple times. The two solutions I've used for this problem are:
1. setting a limit to how many items can be in the list:

```
if len(self.rect_list) > 5):
     self.rect_list = self.rect_list[:5]
```

and two; deleting any more elements then a specified number:

```
if len(self.text_rect_list) > len(self.sub_items):
                del self.text_rect_list[:len(self.sub_items)]
```